# Compare two lists and update only if the first list if condition match on second list

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I have 2 lists (say calList and checkerList)

1. I need to check a condition satisfies on checkerList
2. If so update the item's value of that calList
3. The final calList should be the complete calList (which was updated or not).

What I have tried:

```
resultantCalList =  calList .Where(item1 =>
                    checkerList.Any(item2 => 
                        item1.VendorFieldId == item2.Id
                         && item2.VendorId == vendorId 
                         && item2.Sensitive
                         ))
                            .Select(s => {s.Value = 10; return s; })
                            .ToList();
```

This gives only the collection of updated items only, i.e. the resultantCalList  contains only the list of items whose value got updated. The items which did not have a match doesn't get included in the `resultantCalList`.

Can you please give me a lambda query that gives a list with all items in calList which will have both updated values (if match has been found) and original values (if match wasn't found)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the `Where` clause inside the `Select` statement will avoid filter the contents of calList before it's returned with `ToList`.

```
resultantCalList =
    calList.Select(item1 =>
        {
            if (checkerList.Any(item2 =>
                item1.VendorFieldId == item2.Id
                && item2.VendorId == vendorId
                && item2.Sensitive))
            {
                item1.Value = 10;
            }

            return item1;
        })
    .ToList();
```